How to list the URI of an installed Windows universal app?
How can I get the URI of an installed Windows universal app (e.g.: ms-photos:)?
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *photos*

for example will list something like this:
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.Photos
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 2024.11070.31001.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2024.11070.31001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2024.11070.31001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-13445XXXXX-11579XXXXX-34010XXXXX-1001 [Luca]: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.5_5001.214.1843.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.33519.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.33728.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok

but I can't see the "ms-photos" info, required for example to create a desktop shortcut for the UWP app... How can I get the exact URI of an installed app using Prompt or PowerShell?
